# How to initialize a std::function using std::bind?

Tags: std-function

I have a class which takes a function, f1, as input, and it has another member function f2  which is defined by fixing a part of the arguments of f1. I tried to initialize the f2 using std::bind, but it gave the error **error: no matching function for call to ‘std::function<double(const double&)>::function()’**.

The code is like below:

```
template <typename Function>
class B{
    public:
        B(const Function& func_, const double& b): 
        _f1{func_},
        _b{b}, 
        _f2{std::bind(&func_, _b, std::placeholders::_1)}
        {}
    public:
        Function _f1;
        double _b;
        std::function<double(const double&)> _f2;
};
```

The initialization code is

```
double function2(const double& a, const double& b){
    return a+b;
}

using FunctionB = std::function<double(const double&, const double&)>;

int main(){
    B<FunctionB> b1(function, 2.5);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it can be achieved using lambda expressions.

```
using Function1 = std::function<double(const double&)>;
template <typename Function>
class A {
public:
    A(const Function& func_, const double& b_): 
    _b{b_}, 
    _f{func_},
    _f1{[this](const double &x){return _f(x, this->_b);}}
    {}

    Function _f;
    double _b;

    Function1 _f1;

    void call_f1(const double& x){
        cout << "calling f1" << endl << _f1(x) << endl;
    }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
double f(const double& a, const double& b){
    return a+b;
}
using Function = std::function<double(const double&, const double&)>;

int main(){
    A<Function> a{f, 2.5};

    a.call_f1(9.5);

    return 0;
}
```

and output is 12.

Comment: I tested that f1 can be initialized using lambda expression, but cannot be initialized using std::bind. So now I wonder what is the difference between the two? can anyone explain? Thanks!